# How can I kill Smartscreen service?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell-script, vbscript, regedit

I have software, which is more script then software with binded to exe file. However I can run it without prompt of Smartscreen which informs about possible harm if I launch it.

How can I kill Smartscreen service ? Vbs script would be cool or Powershell one. I did a lot of search and it's all outdated what i found.

Maybe I Can perform regedit command. But Would prefer to kill and disable it :) Too much hassle with certificates and time.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Why would SmartScreen warn you about an exe? You can simply disable it using the options anyway. What is the actual message/dialog you're seeing and what solutions did you try that are outdated?

Comment: That file is for distribution in community and there some people who don't understand how to pass that blue screen.

Comment: I have used github code @ https://gist.github.com/CHEF-KOCH/6185029#file-disablesmartscreen-vbs

Comment: You want to distribute software to a community and want to change their security settings on a whim? Sounds like its a good idea that SmartScreen is blocking your program. In addition you already know what the correct option would be. If you're in controlled company environment push a GPO that disables it.

Comment: https://www.pcworld.com/article/2971725/windows/how-to-reclaim-your-privacy-in-windows-10-piece-by-piece.html?page=2

Answer (score 1):

GUI method

Open Windows Defender Security Center. Click the icon "App & browser control".

To disable SmartScreen for Desktop apps, select the Off option under Check apps and files. To disable SmartScreen for Microsoft Edge, select the Off option under SmartScreen for Microsoft Edge. To disable SmartScreen for Windows Store apps, select the Off option under SmartScreen for Windows Store apps.

Once you disable all three options, the SmartScreen feature will be completely disabled in Windows 10 Creators Update.

Registry method:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"SmartScreenEnabled"="Off"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\PhishingFilter]
"EnabledV9"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppHost]
"EnableWebContentEvaluation"=dword:00000000